ContourPlot does not draw intersection point and draws ragged plots
I have the following implicit equation:
$$
M^{-2\frac{\gamma-1}{\gamma+1}}(r)+\frac{\gamma-1}{2}M^{\frac{4}{\gamma+1}}(r) = \frac{g(r)}{g_0}\left( M_0^{-2\frac{\gamma-1}{\gamma+1}}+\frac{\gamma-1}{2}M_0^{\frac{4}{\gamma+1}} \right)
$$
and I would like to plot the solution where  $M_0$ and $g_0$ are constants. Let's consider that I know specific $g_0$ and $M_0$, then I can do:
{γ, ρ1, rc, fm, r1, σ1, f1, fc, γ1, γ1b, γ2, γ3, γ4, γ4b} = {1.1`, 1.0597781706674332`, 4.504057225336586`, 3, 1.5`, 0.1`, 0.986524106001829`, 0.9006579368641827`, 0.050000000000000044`, 19.999999999999982`, 1.9047619047619047`, 0.09523809523809532`, 0.8499999999999999`, 16.999999999999982`};
eqn1=γ1 m^γ2+m^-γ3-γ4 (r/rc)^(2γ3) (r+ρ1)/r ((fm Exp[(r-r1)/σ1]+f1)/(Exp[(r-r1)/σ1]+1))^γ3*fc;
ContourPlot[eqn1, {r, 1, 6}, {m, 0, 2}]

which results in this:

quite ugly. Interestingly engough, multiplying through by 1/γ1 changes things drastically:
eqn2= m^γ2+γ1b m^-γ3-γ4b (r/rc)^(2γ3) (r+ρ1)/r ((fm Exp[(r-r1)/σ1]+f1)/(Exp[(r-r1)/σ1]+1))^γ3*fc
ContourPlot[eqn2, {r, 1, 6}, {m, 0, 2}]

which gives this:

My question is probably a numerical detail but why? As far as i could see there are no typical numerical issues, all the terms are of order 1 (or probably are I am just missing them). Actually, I would have expected rounding errors for the second case rather than first just seeing the magnitudes by themselves. And even then, I would expect issues in Fortran, I would have though that Mathematica would be more able.
The second question
Consider now that I do not know the constants on the right hand side. So I am really looking for a solution:
$$
\frac{M^{-2\frac{\gamma-1}{\gamma+1}}(r)+\frac{\gamma-1}{2}M^{\frac{4}{\gamma+1}}(r)}{g(r)} = C
$$
Note that $g(r)$ is always positive function defined as
$$
g(r) = \alpha_0 r^{4\frac{\gamma - 1}{\gamma + 1}-1}(r-\rho_0)f^{2\frac{\gamma-1}{\gamma+1}}(r),\\
f(r) = \frac{f_m e^{\frac{r-r_1}{\sigma_1}}+f1}{e^{\frac{r-r_1}{\sigma_1}}-1}
$$
The same issues as above regarding $\gamma_1$ is here as well but notwithstanding, I get:
ContourPlot[eqn4, {r, 1, 6}, {m, 0, 2}]
eqn4=( m^γ2+γ1b m^-γ3) r^(1-2γ3)/(r+ρ1) ((Exp[(r-r1)/σ1]+1)/(fm Exp[(r-r1)/σ1]+f1))^γ3;


As you can see the X point is completely missing and not just that, it is not even approaching that with increasing number of contours. Upon some Taylor fun one can see that the behaviour around the critical point is governed by quadratic terms rather than linear. Which can be seen if one enables CountourLabels.

It seems that Mathematica is just selecting linearly spaced constants for the right hand side. Is there a way to improve this behaviour without too much convoluted work? Or even enforce the X point in the plots? (visually it is clear that there the density of contours is small around the critical points but I am not sure if this information can be translated to mathematica)

All this is described in the documentation: see Options/PlotPoints.

PlotPoints -> 50 will take care of the wiggles:
ContourPlot[eqn1, {r, 1, 6}, {m, 0, 2}, PlotPoints -> 50]


To get the contour line for the X point with eqn4, you can specify the contour values by hand. E.g.:
eqn4 = (m^\[Gamma]2 + \[Gamma]1b  m^-\[Gamma]3)  r^(1 - 
       2 \[Gamma]3)/(r + \[Rho]1)  ((Exp[(r - r1)/\[Sigma]1] + 
        1)/(fm  Exp[(r - r1)/\[Sigma]1] + f1))^\[Gamma]3;
ContourPlot[eqn4, {r, 1, 6}, {m, 0, 2}, 
 Contours -> {11, 49, 11.4951, 11.6, 12}]



While PlotPoints is the remedy, it does not explain the behaviour which I am after.
